# React + Firebase function looping by accident

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, use-state

I have no idea why is my function looping when I use useStates,
Can anyone figure out the problem.
[It loops over and over,this is what appears in my console.log inside the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Xus.png)

```
`function Classtab() {
  const [userName, setuserName] = React.useState(null)
  const [userType, setuserType] = React.useState(null)
  const [userEmail, setuserEmail] = React.useState(null)
  const [userCourse, setuserCourse] = React.useState([])
  const [registeredCourse, setregisteredCourse] = React.useState([])
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user){
        var db = firebase.firestore()
        db.collection('user').doc(user.uid)
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                          setuserName( snapshot.data().name)
                          setuserType( snapshot.data().type)
                          setuserCourse( snapshot.data().course)
                          setuserEmail( user.email)
                          console.log(userCourse)
                userCourse.map(course => {
                  db.doc(course).get().then(
                        snapshot => {setregisteredCourse([...registeredCourse, snapshot.data().name])}
                        )
                      }
                    )
      }).catch(error => console.log(error))}else{}
    })
  return(...)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your auth code into useEffect. What's happening right now is that you are running onAuthStateChanged on every render. And each time that returns, it causes another render, causing it to infinitely add more subscriptions.

I've modified your code to prevent the infinite re-renders and allow userCourse to be the correct value in the promise.then function. What it was originally would've had userCourse in the function to always be an empty array (due to the closure).

```
function Classtab() {
  const [userName, setuserName] = React.useState(null);
  const [userType, setuserType] = React.useState(null);
  const [userEmail, setuserEmail] = React.useState(null);
  const [userCourse, setuserCourse] = React.useState([]);
  const [registeredCourse, setregisteredCourse] = React.useState([]);
  const registeredCourseRef = useRef(registeredCourse);
  useEffect(()=>{
    registeredCourseRef.current = registeredCourse;
  },[registeredCourse])
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('user')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            setuserName(snapshot.data().name);
            setuserType(snapshot.data().type);
            const userCourse = snapshot.data().course;
            setuserCourse(userCourse);
            setuserEmail(user.email);
            console.log(userCourse);
            userCourse.map((course) => {
              db.doc(course)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                  setregisteredCourse((registeredCourse)=>[
                    ...registeredCourse,
                    snapshot.data().name,
                  ]);
                });
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      } else {
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  //Need to have registeredCourse in the dependency array
  //Or have it in a ref
  }, []);
  // return(...)
}
```

Comment: It doesnt render anything now

Comment: I messed up the location of my parentheses, hopefully this will work better now

Comment: I got most of it, but here's a problem, if I didn't have `registeredCourse` in the brackets, it won't push the state. If I have it on the brackets, it starts to loop again

Comment: I've fixed it by using the set state callback function.